# read html from c#, '' is not a supported encoding name error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

i'm triying to read a html from c# like this:

```
      public string getHTMLIcon() {
            string url = @"http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.5.1/img/profileicon/1258.png";
            string data = string.Empty;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = null;

                if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                }

                data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();
            }
            return data;
        }
```

But is getting me the next error: '' is not a supported encoding name.

If i try get the html without the encoding i get the next: ‰PNG  IHDR€€L\öœgAMA± ...

Comment: So is the encoding necessary?

Comment: if i didn't use, i get that text, but only in that web, not in google for example.

Comment: But you're requesting a PNG image - text encoding is irrelevant.

Comment: not in google? Not sure what you mean there. as @DavidKemp said, it's an image, encoding is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have my methods for downloading an image:

```
        public static Stream DownloadImage(string url, string referer)
        {
            try
            {
                var u = new Uri(url);
                HttpWebRequest request;

                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(u);

                request.Referer = referer;
                request.UserAgent = "userAgent";

                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response != null)
                {
                    return response.GetResponseStream();
                }
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {
                Logging.Write($"WEB ERROR {url} \n" + wex.Message);
                throw;
            }

            return null;
        }

    public static void DownloadImage(string url, string referer, string localFilePath)
    {
        Stream stream = DownloadImage(url, referer);

        using(FileStream file = File.Create(localFilePath))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Stream.CopyTo` has been available since .Net 4, and would simplify the code a lot.

Comment: yes, that is actually a code from my old .NET 2.0 project. I have updated it with the stream.CopyTo, so I deleted the last method. It is really simpler now ;)

Comment: if you're taking code review hints - the `FileStream file` should be in a using statement, and you can drop the `file.Close()` call then too